# Disabling a textbox with check event of a checkbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

I want to disable & enable a textbox with check /uncheck event of a checkbox using Jquery.
The following code is not working for me. Am I missing anything?

Should I use onclick event or oncheck event of checkbox???

**NB:** I put alert statements & found that, if block alert is getting called multiple times, but else part is not getting called even a single time.

My CSHTML has :
 @Html.CheckBox("chkprivate", new { @onclick = "Private_Checked();" })

My JS code has :

```
function Private_Checked() {
    $("#chkprivate").click(function () {

        // if ($('#chkprivate').attr("Checked") == true) {
        if ($('#chkprivate').is(':checked')) {
            { $('#Customer_Name_Ext').attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
        }
        else {
            { $('#Customer_Name_Ext').removeAttr("disabled"); }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function Private_Checked() {
    $("#chkprivate").click(function () {
        $('#Customer_Name_Ext').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
}
```

Comment: best one I've seen so far

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function Private_Checked(){

$("#chkprivate").click(function (){

    if ($('#chkprivate').is(':checked')){
        $('#Customer_Name_Ext').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
        $('#Customer_Name_Ext').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});}
```